# Is there an utility that helps writing the file used by AutoHotkey?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

Is there a utility that helps writing the file used by [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Comment: Notepad! But seriously, what are you looking for? Syntax highlighting? A cursory search indicates plugins are available for Eclipse and vim. This is an answer due to low reputation.

Comment: What features are you looking for in an Autohotkey IDE?

Comment: I am just looking for something that helps me writing the script without to remember the syntax. I just started using AutoHotkey, and I have to read all the times the documentation to remember the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, AutoScriptWriter is bundled with the tool and it will record your actions and create the script for you.

Comment: Does it work also when I want to replace a string with another one? Most of the hot keys I use are triggered by a string I write, and that it's replaced when I press the space bar.

Comment: It will just record whatever actions you do and you can always modify the script it creates afterwards. It has worked well for me. Give it a try and see if that is what you are looking for.